# How do you find the length of total Modbus/TCP data?

Tags: modbus

The Modbus/TCP packet includes the length section, which is the length of the total Modbus/TCP data minus 6 bytes. How do you figure out the length of the total Modbus/TCP data?

https://www.scadaforce.com/modbus

Answer (score 1):

> Length - the length of the total Modbus/TCP data minus 6 bytes
>
> How do you figure out the length of the total Modbus/TCP data?

You must read this field then subtract '6' from the value.  That result is the "length of the total Modbus/TCP data."

So, in order to implement this (a modbus-receiver) in C/C++ for example, you need to implement some manner of "framing" loop where you read a fixed-length modbus header, then you read the length specified in the header into memory.